# What are Anglicans' opinion about Muhammad (founder of Islam)?

Tags: islam, anglicanism

I heard from many Christians that they believe that Muhammad is a false prophet. Some other Christians believe he is prophet from God. What do Anglicans believe about Islam especially its founder? (EDIT - [Here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/what-is-the-view-of-islam-within-the-catholic-church) is viewpoints of Catholics, but I would like to know about Anglicans' opinions as well)

Thank you.

Comment: "Some other Christians believe he is prophet from God." About 0.0001% of Christians would say this. Unfortunately they probably are mostly Anglican.

Comment: @curiousdannii, do you have any evidence for that claim?  It sounds like you're bashing Anglicans.

Comment: @Schuh If you watch out for it, then [new stories like this](http://www.christiantoday.com/article/dean.of.westminster.defends.inclusion.of.muslim.prayer.in.abbey.service/53148.htm) are unfortunately common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anglican would, for the most part, not disagree with the assessment given by the Catholic church in the linked questions. Islamic teaching - specifically the teaching of Muhammed in the Quran - is explicitly and intentionally contradictory with Christian teaching and Christian scriptures. It would be hard to make the case of Muhammad being a 'true prophet of God', just as it would be very hard for a Muslim to admit that the New Testament was truly the inspired word of God.

A number of Anglicans (like other denominations) regard the historic Christian teachings as as 'of their time' rather than binding historical truths. For them it would be more plausible to accept that Muhammad was a prophet to the same extent as other Jewish prophets. However their number is rather small as a fraction of Christians in general. Of interest might be the writings of Kenneth Cragg, former Anglican Archbishop of Egypt, who has written interesting books on Muhammad from the Anglican (specifically Liberal Anglican) point of view.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, Muslims believe that Quran is the word of God, in such a way that even one single alphabet of it is not different from what God was talking to Muhammad through Gabriel [some people doing some math on alphabets and words of Quran!]. Also, they believe that the Holy Bible 'was' the word of Jesus (not God) but it has been changed a lot through the history. Not only Quran is not consistent with the Old&New Testament, but also it has many historical and ethical contradictions itself (e.g., denying Jesus' resurrection, splitting the moon by Muhammad, etc).

Comment: @AlphaE You're not using the word 'alphabet' correct...

Comment: @curiousdannii I read somewhere recently (ELL SE, perhaps), that using *alphabet* to mean *letter* is a feature of Indian English.