# Does the Southern Baptist Convention consider other religions evil, demonic, and satanic?

Tags: satan, demons, other-religions, southern-baptist

Does the Southern Baptist Convention consider other religions like Hinduism, Buddhism and Islam evil, demonic, and satanic?

Comment: I think it is better to hear from the people who are already following this denomination. They would have much more knowledge. If I try reading on my own I end up confusing myself a lot. Also it would add to the knowledge base of this stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [SBC's FAQ](http://www.sbc.net/faqs.asp), the best place to look for SBC views on various issues is in their resolutions:

> The Southern Baptist Convention makes official statements regarding specific issues by means of resolutions passed at our annual gatherings each June.

The SBC has a searchable online database of all their resolutions, and search results for each of the three keywords you mention can be found here:

- [*evil*](http://www.sbc.net/resolutions/search/results.asp?query=evil) (65 results)
- [*demonic*](http://www.sbc.net/resolutions/search/results.asp?query=demonic) (0 results)
- [*satanic*](http://www.sbc.net/resolutions/search/results.asp?query=satanic) (2 results)

The word "satanic" is used in reference only to crimes against children through history (in 2009) and the rock band Marilyn Manson (in 1999).

The word "evil" is more widely used in its statements, but we can further filter the results against the words *islam*, *muslim*, *buddhism*, *buddhist*, *hinduism*, and *hindu* using the site's "filter by keyword" option.  Doing so gives no resolutions – thus we can say that the SBC does not directly call any of these religions evil, demonic, or satanic.

Perhaps the closest the SBC gets to making such a claim is in its regular decrying of persecution of Christians.  For example, in 2001, the SBC issued a statement [on the genocide in Sudan](http://www.sbc.net/resolutions/962/on-the-genocide-in-sudan), in which it strongly criticized the "extremist Islamic regime of Khartoum."  But it did not directly criticize the *religion* of Isalm.